# Check if variable Is PDO Object?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a universal function that I use for processing SQL. I am getting this error (just a few times a day, not frequently).

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class PDO could not be converted to string in...
```

Basically, an array of values is passed for a function that I am using, and I must have slipped up in my code and placed a PDO object in that array.

I need to make an array_filter function that checks if the variable is a PDO object. How do I do a simple if statement for this?

```
if($var == PDO)
```

Edit: Thanks for the great answers! In case anyone is interested, here is how I solved the problem. I was able to find where the invalid input was coming from.

```
$before=$original_array;
$after = array_filter($before, "find_error");
if(count($before)!=count($after)){
    $error=print_r(debug_backtrace(false),true);
    $arr=print_r($before,true);
    send_message("admin@email.com","Error Report",$arr.$error); 
//send_message is a simple function for sending emails. You could also write information to a txt file, etc.
}

function find_error($var){
    return !($var instanceof PDO);
}
```

Comment: See my edited answer, I would recommend you DON'T use this solution, but correct the error that puts a PDO object into your array.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what I was trying to do. I needed to generate a backtrace so I could see what script was doing this. The array_filter just let me know if the array was invalid. See me code above.

Comment: Ah, ok. Good luck, I'm glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

instanceof is used to determine whether a PHP variable is an instantiated object of a certain class:

```
if($var instanceof PDO) {
   // your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [instanceof](http://php.net/instanceof) for this.

```
if($var instanceof PDO){
    //code here
}
```

However you say

> I must have slipped up in my code and placed a PDO object in that array

I would recommend that you find and correct that slip up, otherwise you may be storing other problems for yourself as you continue development and possibly pass that array to other parts of your application.

Always cure the problem, rather than focusing on treating a symptom.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are trying to cure the symptom instead of disease.
2. You are trying it out of mere speculation.

What are you trying to do is called "error message suppression". With desired `if` statement, already brought to you by good Samaritans, you're just closing your eyes pretending that there is no error in the program flow. While it remains.

A good programmer have to ask "how to track down the error and how to fix it", not "how to gag it".

So, you have to use `debug_backtrace()` to track the place where wrong data were added. this function have to be placed in the line marked by the error message you have.
Then you need to debug the code to make sure that your assumption of adding PDO result is right.
And finally fix the error.

It seems you managed to solve the problem the right way while I was writing this answer. But I got to leave it here for the future readers.

Comment: Yeah I agree that you should focus on the overall problem rather than a symptom of it. But...sometimes you need to focus strongly on a symptom in order to find out what the problem actually is.